# How to define a function with paramters in expo native module

Tags: kotlin, expo

I have the following kotlin code:

```kotlin
package expo.modules.oppwa

import android.content.Context;

import expo.modules.kotlin.modules.Module
import expo.modules.kotlin.modules.ModuleDefinition
import com.oppwa.mobile.connect.provider.*
import com.oppwa.mobile.connect.payment.*
import com.oppwa.mobile.connect.payment.card.CardPaymentParams
import com.oppwa.mobile.connect.exception.*


class OppwaModule : Module(), ITransactionListener {

  override fun definition() = ModuleDefinition {

    Name("Oppwa")

    Function("validateCard") { cardNumber: String ->
      CardPaymentParams.isNumberValid(cardNumber, true)
    }

    Function("pay") { checkoutId: String, cardBrand: String, cardNumber: String, cardHolder: String, cardExpiryMonth: String, cardExpiryYear: String, cardCVV: String, callbackUrl: String, isLive: Boolean ->  // Line 23
      try {
        // do stuff here
        "ok"  // return ok on sucess
      } catch (e: PaymentException) {
        e.message  // return error message on failure
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error on gradle log:

```
[stderr] 
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/modules/oppwa/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/oppwa/OppwaModule.kt:23:21 Type mismatch: inferred type is (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Boolean) -> Any? but () -> Any? was expected

[stderr] 
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/modules/oppwa/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/oppwa/OppwaModule.kt:23:23 Expected no parameters
```

**Edit 1:** fixed the first error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/module-api/#function):

> The function can receive up to 8 arguments. This is due to the limitations of generics in both Swift and Kotlin, because this component must be implemented separately for each arity.

I am receiving 9 arguments which is over the limit.